# Is it possible to COMPLETELY replace the start menu? 

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I plan to make a replacement for the Windows 7 start menu, and I would like to know if that's even possible. I understand that the start menu is part of explorer.exe but I do not intend to replace explorer.exe.

1. Is it possible to launch the replacement start menu by clicking the native start orb?
2. Is it also possible to launch the replacement by pressing the Windows key or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> ?
3. Is the Windows key a macro for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> ? or is it two different hotkeys that do the same thing?
4. May I know if there is any software that do any one of these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite happy with [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/). As for your 3<sup>rd</sup> question, AFAIK they're two hotkeys for the same action.

Comment: I have tried it and it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer recommends Classic Shell.  That fine product was discontinued quite a few years ago (as of 2017 December).

The project was continued as an open-source project on GitHub, under the name Open Shell.  It is available here:
https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu

I've tried Open Shell, and I recommend it as an updated answer to this question.